# Is there any way to compact app.js file in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am using vuejs with laravel blade file (laravel mix too). But When i run ‘npm run watch’ on local, it built about 13 MB of app.js !
When i run ‘npm run pord’ on server it makes 6 mb !
So, the users face slowness every time i deploy new task.
I have few role permission (main panel and school panel).
Main panel has full control over all things. But school panel has few component.
We use blade file which call a master component and master component may have one or more components that are SPA([Tab based)](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/tabs/). Means when user click other tab it loads another component but if the user click on sidebar menu the page (laravel blade file) reloads and load another page with tabs.

I don’t need to load all component for school panel as this panel has limited permission.
Is there any way so that i can load component specific js file instead of one js(app.js) file?
Is there any way to compact all packages in single file and component file in another js file?(as whenever i deploy changes user have to download whole js file again)
[image]

Comment: You have one app.js? app.js+vendor.js?

Comment: public/app.js only one js @PetrAveryanov

Comment: Look into "vendor bundle extraction".  It's as easy as calling `mix.extract()` and adding a couple extra script tags to your view for the bundle and manifest.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#vendor-extraction for more details

Answer (score 0):

You start with changing your build, so it creates two bundles:

```
app.d1f04bb8.js (your code)
vendor.b9f38bcd.js (libraries)
```

both are cached, so when you do small change -- user will need to load only new app.js.

You can go further and make more vendor bundles, more app bundles, lazy-load bundles etc. -- which one you need is very specific.

P.S. Of course, make sure that your code is minified.

Comment: `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');` this is my webpack.mix.js where i can command mix to make separate js file that you mentioned above? Please describe. @Petr Averyanov

Comment: you can start trying approach here: https://medium.com/@sehmbimanvir/laravel-vue-js-boilerplate-44f1d88f2cc0 with .extract(['vue']), or you may ask another question with Laravel tag and put your config there, so some laravel experts which I am not can help u.